# Raspberry pi as server with either netcat or code

Tags: python, server, connection

When I configure the Raspberry PI as server using Netcat:

> > > nc -l -v 1234

and other computer as client using also Netcat:

> > > nc -v [IP dir] 1234

everything is OK and you can connect both computers and transmit as many messages as you want.
But if I use the next Python code instead of Netcat to configure the Raspberry as server:

```
import socket
mysoc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
adir = ("", 1234)
mysoc.bind(adir)
mysoc.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = mysoc.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data == b'\n':
        break
    else:
        print ("Got a request!")
        print (data)
conn.close()
mysoc.close()
```

then I can connect too but after sending a message, the client can't send more messages. It has to be disconnected and connected again and then, the client computer can send an only message.

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: You are accepting a new socket every iteration of your loop.  I think that instead you want to call recv multiple times on the same connection.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on mkimball's comment...

Each time your code goes around the loop, it accepts an incoming connection, on which it does exactly one `recv`.   Next time round the loop it throws it away (unclosed) and gets a new one, on which it does exactly one `recv`, and so on.

Perhaps this is more what you want:

```
import socket
mysoc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
adir = ("", 1234)
mysoc.bind(adir)
mysoc.listen(5)
conn, addr = mysoc.accept()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data == b'\n':
        break
    else:
        print ("Got a request!")
        print (data)
conn.close()
mysoc.close()
```

---

One more thing to beware of: if you test this a few times, you'll probably see your whole command coming in a single `recv` -- but that's not guaranteed to happen.  If you're not lucky, it could be split into several chunks.  You can easily see this by passing in a very long command (several thousand bytes of text) - but very long input isn't the only thing which can make this happen.

I'll leave how to deal with this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: 1 kB should usually get slurped by a single read but you are correct that it is not *necessarily* the case.  This is why even the simplest exchanges require some kind of minimal protocol (in this case looking for `\n` should be fine).